# validating java.util.Map against xsd

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, saxparser

I have an xsd that generates a jaxb class. For which I have created an XML adapter for generic maps. This adapter passes unit tests, and the type of the generated variable is appropriately a map as intended. The catch though is that when attempting to validate an object created from this scenario, I get "Cannot resolve 'hashMap' type to a definition for element 'autoExecuteArguments'. I have fiddled quite a bit, but always end with some variation of the above error. These two bindings are not used together, but exemplify attempts at coming to some resolution.

```
      <xjc:javaType name="java.util.Map" xmlType="mp:MapTypeEntry"
        adapter="mil.dod.th.ose.core.impl.mp.UtilMapConverter" />

 <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="resources/missionProgramSchema/MissionProgram.xsd">
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='MissionProgramInstance']">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='autoExecuteArguments']">
            <jaxb:property>
                <jaxb:baseType name="java.util.HashMap">
                    <xjc:javaType name="java.util.Map"
                    adapter="//core.impl.mp.UtilMapConverter" />
                </jaxb:baseType>
            </jaxb:property>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

I am confident that the last one is a mockery to bindings, and as such I have not been able to make it work with a large amount of tweeking, I get '[ERROR] compiler was unable to honor this property customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.

Next the converter:

```
@XmlSeeAlso(UtilMapConverter.MapType.class)
public class UtilMapConverter<K, V> extends XmlAdapter<UtilMapConverter.MapType<K,V>, Map<K, V>> {

@Override
public UtilMapConverter.MapType<K, V> marshal(final Map<K, V> map) 
{
    final MapType<K, V> mapType = new MapType<K, V>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) 
    {
        final MapTypeEntry<K, V> mapEntryType = new MapTypeEntry<K, V>(); 
        mapEntryType.setKey(entry.getKey());
        mapEntryType.setValue(entry.getValue());
        mapType.getEntry().add(mapEntryType);
    }
    return mapType;
}

@Override
public Map<K, V> unmarshal(final UtilMapConverter.MapType<K, V> genericMap) 
{
    final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();

    for (MapTypeEntry<K, V> mapEntryType : genericMap.getEntry()) 
    {
        map.put(mapEntryType.getKey(), mapEntryType.getValue());
    }
    return map;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public static class MapType<K, V> 
{
    private List<MapTypeEntry<K, V>> m_Entry = new ArrayList<MapTypeEntry<K, V>>();

    public MapType()
    {  
    }

    public MapType(final Map<K, V> map) 
    {
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> e : map.entrySet()) 
        {
            m_Entry.add(new MapTypeEntry<K, V>(e));
        }
    }
    @XmlElement
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "mapType")
    public List<MapTypeEntry<K, V>> getEntry() 
    {
        return m_Entry;
    }
    public void setEntry(final List<MapTypeEntry<K, V>> entry) 
    {
        this.m_Entry = entry;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public static class MapTypeEntry<K, V> 
{

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "key")
    protected K m_Key;


    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "value")
    protected V m_Value;


    public MapTypeEntry() 
    {
    }


    public MapTypeEntry(final Map.Entry<K, V> entry) 
    {
        m_Key = entry.getKey();
        m_Value = entry.getValue();
    }


    @XmlElement
    public K getKey() 
    {
        return m_Key;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public V getValue() 
    {
        return m_Value;
    }
}
```

I am aware that I have a mess. 
I am just beside myself trying to figure out what is helping, what is hurting and what is just plain silly. 
Finally the xsd:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns="http://core/mp/model" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" targetNamespace="http://core/mp/model"
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" elementFormDefault="qualified"
id="MissionProgramInstance" jaxb:version="2.1"
jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
<xs:include schemaLocation="MissionProgram.xsd" />
<xs:element name="MissionProgramInstance">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="program" type="MissionProgram"
                minOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="autoExecuteArguments" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <jaxb:property>
                            <jaxb:baseType name="java.util.Map" />
                        </jaxb:property>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="autoExecuteEnabled" type="xs:boolean"
            use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="assetDep" use="optional">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:list itemType="xs:string" />
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="physicalLinkDep" use="optional">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:list itemType="xs:string" />
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="linkLayerDep" use="optional">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:list itemType="xs:string" />
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="transportLayerDep" use="optional">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:list itemType="xs:string" />
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="imageStreamDep" use="optional">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:list itemType="xs:string" />
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="programDep" use="optional">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:list itemType="xs:string" />
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="MissionProgram">
    <xs:sequence>
        <!--This field holds source data for a mission program -->
        <xs:element name="source" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="MapType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="autoExecuteArgument" type="MapTypeEntry">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <jaxb:property>
                        <jaxb:baseType name="//core.mp.impl.UtilMapConverter.MapType" />
                    </jaxb:property>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleType name="MapTypeEntry">
    <xs:list itemType="xs:anySimpleType" />
</xs:simpleType>
    </xs:schema>
```

There is a bit of redundancy in this current presentation. I am new to xsd, and jaxb. And I have tried to make sense of all this, but despite attempting to research, I think that I am looking in the wrong places, as I seem to find pieces, but not explanations of all this working together.
Here is one of my main resources in trying to put at least parts this altogether: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html .
Also the javadocs for the xml adapter, along with gobs of browsing here and there. 
Thank you if you took time to at least ponder "what would you do?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i would do (and have done), is write a clean xsd and use xjc to generate the java classes.  if you need a more "coder-friendly" data structure, then write your own code to transform the jaxb objects post-deserialization.  trying to force the xml to fit how you think you want your data structures to look is generally an exercise in frustration and will make your life difficult as your project transforms over time.

Comment: That is what I expected. Thank you for you quick response.